# Can I install another OS on a Sony VAIO E Series laptop without any problems?

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio

I have never owned a laptop. This is the first time i am going to buy one. I don't know the details about installing another OS apart from what comes with it.

I am going to buy a new Sony VAIO E Series laptop. I hate the Windows 7 Home Basic that comes with it. **I want to install Windows 7 Ultimate.** I heard someone recommend dell instead of vaio because of issues with updates to drivers for sony laptops, when new OS arrives. I want to install Win7 Ultimate. Can I do it on a sony vaio e series laptop?

Comment: not a good idea. the CD that comes with Sony laptops is a special OEM version of the OS that has special built-in and non-downloadable drivers.   another copy of a windows CD will probably not work.

Comment: @djangofan Oh really?  Could you please tell me what this link is?  http://esupport.sony.com/perl/select-system.pl  You can download virtually ANY driver for any PC that any major computer manufacturer has ever produced. The link I gave you is for Sony's driver repository, contains the exact same drivers you claim are only on the OEM version. There is nothing "special" about a base OEM version of Windows, though a manufactures specific version may have other software (including drivers) built in. The important difference between OEM and Retail is how they are activated and registered.

Comment: maybe someone else will give a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a problem with drivers or anything else since your laptop originally came with Windows 7.  The same drivers will be used for Windows 7 Home Basic and Windows 7 Ultimate (and all versions of Windows 7 for that matter).  You will be able to simply download the drivers from Sony and install them on your new OS.  If Sony is being a b**** about their drivers (which is possible) then it is always possible to unzip them from their installer package and install them manually.  I do recall doing that more than once on my Vaio desktop when I installed a retail version of XP versus the OEM version it came with.

In summary any issues you might have installing Windows Ultimate are minimal and can easily be worked through.

On a side note I haven't seen any major usage differences between Windows 7 Home Basic and Windows 7 and any other version of Windows 7.  If you looking for more features such as Media Center, BitLocker, etc., then upgrading might be a good idea.  If you simply hate the look and feel of Windows 7 Home Basic then I wouldn't bother upgrading.

Comment: With Sony laptops (and I know from experience) , you wont have much luck with ANY other copy of any operating system (including windows7) unless you use the copy that came on the system rescue CD that came with the laptop.   Any other attempt and your milage will vary or will be cut short.

Comment: @djangofan that is totally wrong. You can put ANY x86 OS on ANY x86 computer and have full functionality of that computer's hardware IF drivers are available. Obviously the drivers ARE available because the system came with Windows 7.  I have had DOZENS of OEM computers that I have changed the OS on with absolutely no problem at all. And to say your "milage" (I assume you mean "mileage") would be cut short is totally ridiculous. What is a non-OEM version of Windows 7 going to do?  Wear out the transistors faster? I don't know where you got your "experience" from but I wouldn't go back.

Comment: If you have a driver disc from Sony, then you are good to go.  Otherwise, take a moment and go to the drivers page on the Sony website and compare it with your hardware list in the device manager.  Downloading the drivers beforehand will save you a huge headache.  I would download them all to a flash drive so they are handy when you need them.  I would strongly recommend, at the minimum, download the proper ethernet drivers and if its there the SATA disk controller drivers.  This will allow you to read the disk and connect to the internet once windows is installed.